# why doesn't IE8 refresh textbox right away?(Jquery)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have 3 radio buttons and one textbox in my page. These 3 radio controls, representing corresponding choices and among them, the third one enables textbox that is disabled by default. If user clicks any one from the first twos after clicking the third, the textbox will be emptied(if user input any) and disabled again. The problem is, in IE, the textbox isn't emptied not until I click back once again on the said textbox. I've used jquery val methods as well as attr but nothing seems to work. You can see my code as follows. The very same code works just fine in Mozilla. I'm not sure why IE is having problem.

```
        m.bind_eventform = function(){
     $('input[name=poster]').change(function(){
      if($('input[name=poster]:checked').val()==2) $('#poster_other').removeAttr('disabled');
      else if(!($('#poster_other').is(':disabled'))) 
      {
       $('#poster_other').attr('disabled','disabled');
       $('#poster_other').attr('value',''); //this one doesn't work
       $('#poster_other').val(''); //as well as this one
      }
     });
    };

$(document).ready(m.bind_eventform);
```

*EDIT - Markup added per request*

```
<div class="formwrapper">
                    <div style="float:left"><input type="radio" name="poster" value="0" checked="checked" style="float:left;">
                        <span style="float:left;margin:0 0 0 5px">owner</span></div>
                    <div style="float:left;margin-left: 80px"><input type="radio" name="poster" value="1" style="float:left;">
                        <span style="float:left;margin:0 0 0 5px">agent</span></div>
                    <div style="float:right;margin-left:40px"><input type="radio" name="poster" value="2"  style="float:left;">
                        <span style="float:left;margin:0 0 0 5px">others</span>
                        <input type="text" id="poster_other" size="40" style="float:left;margin:0 0 0 5px" disabled="disabled"></div>
                    <div style="clear:both"></div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Luke, use the force (and some <br/> too if possible) :)

Comment: With the help of jsbin, I found the culprit. It's jquery 1.3.2 bug which causing this whole problem. It works just fine in 1.4.0. Thanks guys.

Comment: No problem man! Are you sure its a ´jQuery´ bug? it's hard those guys missed such a nasty one.

Comment: I've changed different Jquery version one at a time and tested the code. Anything below 1.4.0, doesn't fix the problem. Starting from 1.4.0, it works fine. If only jsbin stores the code on their site, I would give u link. But that's not the case. The code is stored in client side.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
$('#poster_other').val('');
```

**before** calling:

```
$('#poster_other').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Maybe you can setup a http://www.jsbin.com page with the non-working code

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your IE is running in IE8 browser mode and IE8 document mode (Check in Tools.Developer Tools). Sometimes it runs under Quirks or compatibility mode and that can cause problem.

This is what I do to make sure IE8 is rendering my html in IE8 mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>      
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

The important part is the X-UA-Compatible meta tag.

Comment: Does that statement would confine my page to IE8 only and would be rendered unpredictably in other IE versions? I'm not family with this usage. Anyway, I've added that statement but still, IE refuse to function as I want.

Comment: Lower IE version will ignore the meta, higher IE version (say IE9) will render the html in IE8 mode.

Answer (score 0):

Just found the culprit with the help of Jsbin. It's jquery 1.3.2 bugs which causing this problem. After change using to 1.4.0, it works as I wanted. Thanks to all for prompt replies.
Cheers

Comment: The newly assigned value of disabled textbox will not reflect until the textbox is clicked again. It's only in IE8. I can't comment on the rest of the IE versions cuz I don't have them. You can see the detail of the problem in op.